# accessing amp-state JSON values

Tags: amp-html

I'm trying to populate a value 'carouselpos' from a server, and then call goToSlide against that value.

I've setup an amp-state, like this:
amp-state id="myRemoteState" src="...server URL here..."

And verified that the state is being populated:
AMP.printState()
log.js:163 40022 "[amp-bind]" "{"myRemoteState":{"items":[{"carouselpos":"37"}]}}"

I'd now like to use that carouselpos value in a call to goToSlide, as below, but whichever way I try using dotted notation doesn't seem to work. I'm sure I'm making a stupid mistake, can anyone help clarify what that mistake is please?

carousel.goToSlide(index=myRemoteState.items.carouselpos)

Answer (score 1):

goToSlide doesn't support variables as a value, you might consider filing a feature request for this on [Github](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/new). An alternative approach is to bind the current slide to an amp-state variable:

```
<amp-carousel controls
    type="slides"
    width="400"
    height="300"
    [slide]="carouselpos">...</amp-carousel>
```

Here is a working example:

https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/image_galleries_with_amp-carousel/#linking-carousels-with-amp-bind